# Centering JButtons in a JFrame - Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, layout-manager

I want to manually center multiple `JButton` in a `JPanel` but my pixel count does not add up. It looks like the right side space is smaller then the left. How do I center them properly?

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Checkers");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.setSize(400, 400);
f.setVisible(true);
JButton onePlayer=new JButton("1 Player");
onePlayer.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 30);
add(onePlayer);
onePlayer.setVisible(true);
setLayout(null);
```

Comment: did you try putting f.setVisible(true); at the bottom ? Sometimes that may be the case. There is not any problem else I can see

Comment: Please don't use `null` layout, as swing was designed to be used with layouts. For this, please see the [Swing Layout Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more information.

Comment: why don't you use a `LayoutManager` like `BorderLayout`? If there is no good reason, that will be better.

Comment: `setVisible()` does not have to be called on the `JButton`. After finishing building your GUI, `setVisible()` should only be once called on the `JFrame`. So `f.setVisible(true)` should be the last line of your example.

Comment: 1) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). 2) A `GridBagLayout` with a single component inside it with no (i.e. default) constraints will be centered. That 'single component' might be a `JButton` or a `JPanel` with more than one button, or..

Comment: There might be a scalability problems later down the line, I would advise you to use LayoutManager and nested JPanels to get the desirable outcome. If something isn't exactly where you need it to be, try to use many JPanels (nested or not)